# How to get a minibufer on top of the screen with the visual auto-complete

Tags: minibuffer, config

On the screenshots of Doom Emacs themes (https://github.com/doomemacs/themes/tree/screenshots) I see the minibufer on the top of the screen with the visual autocomplete:
[image]
How to achieve this look and feel of minibuffer in vanilla Emacs?

The only addon doing something like this I found is emacs-mini-frame (https://github.com/muffinmad/emacs-mini-frame). In `ivy-mode` it shows something slightly similar, but the behavior of emacs-mini-frame in XMonad (the WM I use) is very strange (some problems were fixed with ugly hacks of XMonad config, but some still not).

I searched for «minibuffer» in Doom Emacs repo (https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs), but failed to understand, where this look is configured.

Comment: As far as I know, doom uses vertico (not sure, did not check it). Anyway, I have found [this section](https://github.com/minad/vertico#child-frames-and-popups) in the Vertico README.

Comment: @dalanicolai: Thank you! On the screenshot we probably see vertico-posframe: https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/4f23a02877a5f9f6e6612f4c7ea9c050c40dcd68/modules/completion/vertico/packages.el

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. Yes, it's probably Vertico + vertico-posframe + marginalia.el (thank you @dalanicolai!).

- Vertico: https://github.com/minad/vertico
- vertico-posframe: https://github.com/tumashu/vertico-posframe
- marginalia.el: https://github.com/minad/marginalia

I get good enough approximation of the screenshoted functionality with this (bad styled and old-fashioned, of course) `.emacs` code:

```
;; Minibuffer with visual autocomplete and help
(require 'vertico)
(require 'vertico-posframe)
(require 'marginalia)
(vertico-mode)
(vertico-posframe-mode 1)
(marginalia-mode)
```

To get *exactly* the same interface (vertico-posframe on the top of the frame) you need to add to your `.emacs` one more line:

```
(setq vertico-posframe-poshandler #'posframe-poshandler-frame-top-center)
```

(I saw this trick [here](https://github.com/tumashu/vertico-posframe/issues/9#issuecomment-1008603004)).

I found a blog post and a couple of screencasts about Vertico and friends:

- [Using Emacs Episode 80 Vertico, Marginalia, Consult, and Embark](https://cestlaz.github.io/post/using-emacs-80-vertico/)
- [Using Emacs Episode 80 - Vertico, Marginalia, Consult, and Embark (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ffb2at2d7w)
- [System Crafters Live! - Replacing Ivy and Counsel with Vertico and Consult (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtqE-lR2HCA)

I hope after studying all this stuff I'll configure the completion for minibuffer much better.